# Angular Firestore - Search for all documents with reference to specifig document

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to search all documents in collection a with a reference to a specific document in collection b.

All I found here or on google was not working :/

My attemp in my service class

```
  getAsFromB(id) {
      var refB = this.firestore.collection("/collection_b").doc(id);
      console.log(refB);

      return this.firestore
        .collection("/collection_a", (ref) => ref.where("refB", "==", refB))
        .snapshotChanges();
  }
```

All I get is the following error: Unsupported field value: refB = custom Object but log says refB is looking good AngularFirestoreDocument

[image]

what did I forget or what am I doing wrong?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query here:

```
var refB = this.firestore.collection("/collection_b").doc(id);
```

points to a Firestore document, but you need to specify that you want it's reference. To fix it, change that line to this:

```
const refB = this.firestore.collection("/collection_b").doc(id).ref;
```

Here is a modified version of your function that will log out the results of your query to verify that it's returning the expected documents:

```
getAsFromB(id: string) {
   const refB = this.firestore.collection("/collection_b").doc(id).ref;
   console.log(refB);

   return this.firestore
     .collection("/collection_a", (ref) => ref.where("refB", "==", refB))
     .snapshotChanges().subscribe(res => {
       res.forEach(doc => {
         console.log(doc.payload.doc.data());
       })
     });
 }
```

As this is in a service, you'll want to remove the subscribe, I just thought it could be useful for your debugging :)

PS it's also good practice in Typescript to use const and let instead of var.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!
I thought I tried this, but i looked im my browser history and there it also says to add the ".ref" in the where clause which is doubled and thats why it hasn't worked: ```(ref) => ref.where("refB", "==", refB.ref)```